# Repeater and tr runat=server. How to add class to row?

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I need to the attribute `class` (if it doesn't exist) to table row located in a repeater. There's a question is inside the code.

**aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">........
  <ItemTemplate> .....
      <tr runat="server" id="row" >
      .....................
```

**codeBehind**

```
void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                var row= e.Item.FindControl("row");
                //how do I use it? How do I add "class" (if not exists) to "row"?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That object is an HtmlDataRow:

```
HtmlTableRow row = e.Item.FindControl("row") as HtmlTableRow;
if (row != null )
{
    if (string.isNullOrEmpty(row.Attributes["class"])) 
    {
         row.Attributes["class"] = "myClass"; 
    }
    else
    {
         row.Attributes["class"] = string.Format( "{0} {1}", row.Attributes["class"], "myClass");
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do I check if it exists? If it does I need just append my class to existing one.